# How to do linear search and retrieve object in Kotlin?

Tags: android, algorithm, android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel

So I have an `ArrayList<MovieDetailEntity>` which contains a data class I made called `MovieDetailEntity`. In the data class, I have a movie ID which is unique to every movie. I'm trying to retrieve the rest of the properties in the object from linear search.

So currently I have these functions:

```
private fun getMovieDetails():ArrayList<MovieDetailEntity>{
    return DetailDataDummy.getMovieDetail()
}

fun getDetailsById(movieId: String):MovieDetailEntity{
    val details = getMovieDetails()
    var detailEntity: MovieDetailEntity
    for (item in details){
        if (movieId == item.movieId){
            detailEntity = item
            break
        }
    }
    return detailEntity
}
```

I'm trying to get the whole object returned in `fun getDetailsById(movieId: String)` when the ID is matched. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it not already doing that? what is your issue?

Comment: `detailEntity` might not be initialized if no match is found. You need to make it nullable and then you can either return a nullable or return `detailEntity!!` if you are sure there will always be a match. Or the easier way to do all this would be `return getMovieDetails().first { it.movieId == movieId }`

Comment: You could also do `details.find { it.movieId == movieId }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin's standard library provides a lot of functions for doing standard tasks like this without needing to write for loops. Here you can do

```
fun getDetailsById(movieId: String): MovieDetailEntity {
    return getMovieDetails().first {
        it.movieId == movieId
    }
}
```

Note that this will crash if no such item can be found. To not crash but allow a nullable return use `firstOrNull`.